# Different HTML and PDF output formats

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to create a report in rmarkdown but the shape of the output I want is only correct in the HTML file. When I export as PDF the format is differente. The title goes to the middle of the page, there's no space between authors 1 and 2, the date goes to the middle of the page, etc... Do you know why this is happening and what can I do to overcome this?

```
---
title: "açoifjwçoifjwçaofijwaçfijo"
author: '1: lululukuku <br> 2: eeeeeeeeeeeee'
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d, %B, %Y')`"
output:
  html_notebook: default
  pdf_document: default
---



<style type="text/css">

h1.title {
  font-size: 38px;
  color: DarkBlack;
  text-align: left;
}
h4.date {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: DarkBlack;
  float: right;
}

h4.author {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: DarkBlack;
  float: left;
}

div#header {
  overflow: auto;
}

</style>

---
```

The code used to render:

```
rmarkdown::render('aaa.Rmd', 'html_document', 'teste.html')
rmarkdown::render('aaa.Rmd', 'pdf_document', 'teste.pdf')
```

And the outputs:

HTML:

[image: HTML IMAGE]

PDF:

[image: PDF IMAGE]

Comment: Because RMarkdown is not meant to give you the same output for each output format. RMarkdown comes with different default templates for the various output formats. This also means that changing the style of your html document via custom css does not affect the pdf output. If you want to get the exactly the same output you have to write your own templates for each output format.

Comment: Do you know how can I modify for PDF outputs?

Comment: So far I have only adjusted the default templates for html and word. But. pdf output is made via latex. So best it to look for resources on how make a custom latex template for RMarkdown, e.g. https://www.gerkelab.com/blog/2019/04/manipulating-latex-in-rmd/

Comment: Or you can create it to HTML, and then PRINT the HTML file to pdf from the web browser